# Uber/Mockolo Issue: ProtocolAMock.generated: Type 'ProtocolAMock' does not conform to protocol 'ProtocolB'

Tags: ios, swift, mocking, xctest, swift-protocols

**Issues with [Uber's Mockolo](https://github.com/uber/mockolo), generated tests.**

> I have ProtocolA conforming to ProtocolB, ProtocolA has @mockolo
> annotation/wrapper.

Here's my code in the `original target`:

```
/// @mockable
protocol ProtocolA: ProtocolB {}
```

However the ProtocolA.generated.swift shows the following error:

```
// ProtocolAMock.generated: Type 'ProtocolAMock' does not conform to protocol 'ProtocolBmending'
```

Obviously, when redeclare the protocol methods on ProtocolB in ProtocolA's generated mocks files error is gone.

I wonder why Mockolo cannot recognise this, I have also tried adding the @mockable property wrapper for ProtocolB.

I have just started using [Uber/RIBs](https://github.com/uber/RIBs) any help would be much appreciated in advance :)

Thanks
Sai

Link to the same [issue](https://github.com/uber/mockolo/issues/170#issue-1077210751) reported on [uber/mockolo](https://github.com/uber/mockolo) GitHub.

Comment: It is bcz you have not implemented methods of ProtocolB in ProtocolA

Answer (score 0):

I found out my protocol B was not inside the source for mockolo generation.

**Solution:**

check your mockolo script in your build phases

```
./mockolo -s ./Foo.swift -d ./OutputMocks.swift
```

make sure your `protocol B` is inside the -s directory(ofc, also as has @mockolo anotation :))